# OCaml4.04.0でlambdasoupが動かない

Tags: html, ocaml, web-scraping

opam でocaml.4.04.0をインストールしてlambda-soupを使おうとしてインストールしました。

```
 $ opam install lambdasoup
```

しかし、lambdasoupを使うプログラムを書いてコンパイルしようとしてみると、次のようなエラーがでてしまいます。

```
Warning 58: no cmx file was found in path for module Soup, and its interface was not compiled with -opaque
File "hoge.ml", line 1:
Error: Some fatal warnings were triggered (1 occurrences)
```

何か設定が間違っているのでしょうか？

- OS: Ubuntu: 12.04
- opam: 1.2.2
- OCaml 4.04.0
- lambdasoup 0.6

Answer (score 1):

`-w <list>` か `-warn-error <list>` コンパイルスイッチに Warning 58 をエラーと扱うような設定が入っているはずなので、それを外してください。  (参照: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html )

これらのスイッチの使い方の例をあげておきます:

- `-warn-error A-58` : 58以外の警告はすべてエラーとする
- `-w @40..58` : 40から58の警告はエラーとする